# win32com.dll Library not loading

Tags: java, swing, dll, win32com, loadlibrary

I am developing a Java application in Swing.

My application needs the `win32com.dll` (Java Communication API) and the file `javax.comm.properties`.

Normally, I just copy the dll to `C:\Java\jre1.6\bin` and the config file to `C:\Java\jre1.6\lib`.

The code I have written, was this :

```
System.out.println("Loading Library...");
System.out.println("------- " + System.getProperty("java.library.path"));
System.loadLibrary("win32com.dll");
System.out.println("Library Loaded.");
```

Output :

> Loading Library...
>   ------- C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_66\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin/server;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/bin;C:/Program
>   Files/Java/jre1.8.0_66/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine
>   Components\IPT;C:\Users\user\Desktop;;. Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no win32com.dll in java.library.path
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)  at
>   dotMatrix.TicketView1.main(TicketView1.java:16)

But I am getting 'Thread exception' and can't do all that in the target environment. 
Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please share the stacktrace of the exception.

Comment: Try copying the dll into the JRE\lib\ext folder.

Comment: tried the same.. but pblm still exists